# python efficiency: multi-dimensional dicts vs tuple keys

Tags: python

I have a multi dimensional dictionary like so:

`a[id][time][section][day] = 0`

And I'm wondering in populating and using this, wether it's more efficient to go the `dict` route or a tuple as a key like so:

`a[(id,time,section,day)] = 0`

There's a lot of data being loaded and parsed here. Is there a more canonical way to approach this?

Comment: it doesnt *really* matter ... dict lookup is O(1) ... so its probably a little faster to only do one lookup ... but either method should be plenty fast (I doubt this is a bottleneck in your system)